# ionic-native/date-picker StaticInjectorError

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

So I am attempting to use the [DatePicker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker#platforms), however I am getting a `StaticInjectorError`

Here is what I've tried:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TextService} from '@core/services/text/text.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FeaturePage} from '@feature/paths';
import {User} from '@core/classes/user';
import {DatePicker} from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-setup',
    templateUrl: 'setup.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['setup.page.scss'],
})
export class SetupPage {

    user: User;

    constructor(private textService: TextService, private router: Router, private datePicker: DatePicker) {
        this.user = new User();

        this.datePicker.show({
            date: new Date(),
            mode: 'date',
            androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK
        }).then(
            date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
            err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
        );
    }

}
```

and I get the following error:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SetupPage -> DatePicker]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SetupPage -> DatePicker]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePicker!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SetupPage -> DatePicker]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SetupPage -> DatePicker]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePicker!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Usually this happens if you haven't imported the module, however in the documentation there is no module to import?

Comment: Well, did you import it? Usually all `@ionic-native` packages have to be imported in `app.module.ts`'s providers array

Comment: @AugustinR ive added this:     providers: [
        IonicNativePlugin
    ],

is that correct?

Comment: Will write it in an answer for better lisibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add this in `app.module.ts` :

```js
import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';

[...]

@NgModule({
...
providers: [
    ...,
    DatePicker
]
...
})
```

Usually all `@ionic-native` packages have to be imported in `app.module.ts`'s providers array, even if it's not mentioned in the ionic documentation.

Comment: This is correct. Every time you add some plugin, you also have to add it to app.module.ts. And actually it is mentioned in documentation but it's hard to find. "Import the plugin in a @NgModule and add it to the list of Providers."
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/overview

Comment: Marc is using Ionic 4, the correct link is : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/. As you can see, no mention of adding the plugin to `providers` array

Comment: @AugustinR when i do this it works however it provides me with the following error Error occurred while getting date:  cordova_not_available

Comment: When using a native plugin, if it is not compatible with browser, you have to run your app on a device in order to make it work. This is the purpose of Cordova plugins : make native features of devices available in a webview-based application. This is why it does not run on browser.

Comment: This answer solved my problem on a completely unrelated subject with ng2-daterangepicker